# Can you use both fixed-effects and random-effects models in the same meta-analysis? Shouldn't you use just one model?

Tags: random-effects-model, meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model

This is just an example, but I've found many of them:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23216926/

Thank you very much in advance!